# Trim trailing zero n rails from a character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, postgresql

In my PgSQL database, one of my columns is 'character varying'. When I save numbers from an excel file to it, it adds `.0` to the end. How do I trim it?

I've tried `row[1].to_s.strip` but that doesn't trim out the `.0`. Adding `to_i` wouldn't work either, as some values are in the form `45-8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `chomp` for that:

```
row[1].chomp('.0')
```

Quoting from the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-chomp):

> Returns a new `String` with the given record separator removed from the end of str (if present).

Comment: Thanks. I was using row[1].to_s.strip.split('.0')[0]  using an answer from another thread.

Comment: From the docs quote, I suspect that's exactly what `chomp` does internally :)

Comment: Oops :-) I'll take the shorter anyways :-)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:
`row[1].to_s[0, row[1].to_s.index(".0")]`

Comment: This only works if the string always ends with `.0`. If it doesn't, `row[1].to_s.index(".0")` returns `nil` and `row[1].to_s[0, nil]` raises a `TypeError`